# change the value of a variable within a literal function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I'd like to know how to get this result:

```
function() {
   var myVar = "";
   function () {
      myVar += "This is ";
   }
   myVar = "my string";
   alert(myVar); //would like it to display: This is my string
   // only displays: my string
}
```

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect. It would not alert *anything* in the form it's in now.  When asking a question here, it's important to post the actual code you're having a problem with.

Comment: You don't call that function, you only declare it.

Comment: thank you for your comments... but I think you`re missing the point here... the thing that I want to know is how can a change the value of a variable declared within a literal function from within a child literal function to use it out of the child but within the father. Hope you can understand this confusing comment! LOL

Answer (score 3):

You A. have to call a function for it to execute and B. must reorganize you string a bit

```
function() {
   var myVar = "";
   function update() {
      myVar = "This is " + myVar;
   }
   myVar = "my string";
   update();
   alert(myVar); //would like it to display: This is my string
   // only displays: my string
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But i'm using to literal functions, one within the other

Answer (score 1):

You have to *call* the function.

```
var myVar = "";
function someFunction() { // Give it a name
   myVar += "This is ";
}
myVar = "my string";
someFunction(); // and call it
alert(myVar);
```

Comment: oops! `my stringThis is` ??

Comment: I always get thrown for a loop when I see you post Quentin, my name is also Quentin and I always throws me off for a second.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But i'm using two literal functions, one within the other

Comment: You still need to call the function before it will do anything

Comment: I don't think you can (or need to) call a literal function

Comment: You can, and if you want it to do anything, you must. At the moment, you have a function expression that you don't do anything with. You don't call it. You don't assign it to a variable. You just create it and then let it vanish.

Comment: What I want to know is how can I change the value of a variable declared within a literal function from within a child literal function to use it out of the child but within the father. Hope you can understand... this is really confusing!

Comment: You just have to **call the function**.